# How can GlusterFS move thin disks between bricks?

Tags: glusterfs

In a thin provisioning environment, if a file grows bigger and bigger, how can GlusterFS move it between bricks?
The original bricks are full of space, but newly added bricks are nearly empty, How can DHT translator deals that situation?

Answer (score 0):

After adding new brick(s) you can carry out rebalance operation to move files from one brick to other.

But, you won't be able to do this on a per file basis.

Check the below doc.:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_gluster_storage/3.3/html-single/administration_guide/#sect-Rebalancing_Volumes